# SVG logo has unwanted white space above/below, only in Google Webmasters Tools page thumbnail

Tags: css, html, svg, google-search-console

I have submitted my [website](http://bulgaricus.sk) to Google's Webmasters Tools and I am experiencing strange problem. Logo that is inlined svg breaks layout on thumbnail. It has no problems in any modern browser (tested in FF, Webkit/Vivaldi/Chrome/Safari, Edge). The same behaviour is in mobile usability preview, where logo is nearly below bottom edge of screen. The same happens in Bing Webmasters Tools.

As far as it's only a problem of thumbnail I shouldn't be worried, but I'd like to have it fixed.
Logo is in div with 25% width on tablet+, 100% for anything smaller, so it scales automatically.

Is there a way how to debug it? Or is the code for logo incorrect?

```
<h1>  
  <a title="page title" href="/">
    <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="53 450 276 94" enable-background="new 53 450 276 94" xml:space="preserve">
      <title/>
      <desc/>
      <path/>
    </svg>
  </a>
</h1>
```

[image: Google Webmasters Tools page thumbnail]

Comment: Can you include your site as well? I tried using the HTML code you gave me and on JSFiddle, it shows nothing in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found this bug report: [Bug 82489 - SVG Inline content incorrectly sizes](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82489)

and according to it, I applied `style="max-height: 100%"` to my SVG and this fixed all thumbnails and some Android browsers too. So looks like this bug is still present.

**Fixed code**:

```
<h1>
  <a title="page title" href="/">
    <svg version="1.1" style="max-height:100%;" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="53 450 276 94" enable-background="new 53 450 276 94" xml:space="preserve">
      <title/>
      <desc/>
      <path/>
    </svg>
  </a>
</h1>
```